# fetch data using query builder by checking multiple data from same column in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

```
DB::table('products')
->where('status', '=', 'published')
->where('sub_category', '=', 'grooming-wellness')
->where('sub_category', '=', 'beauty-care')
->get();
```

it doesn't work. it returns 0 data.

Comment: What is your goal?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you want to check if a field has a particular value or another value. You can use `whereIn` to achieve this:

```
DB::table('products')
    ->where('status', '=', 'published')
    ->whereIn('sub_category', ['grooming-wellness', 'beauty-care'])
    ->get();
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Query Builder - Where Clauses - Additional Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses) `whereIn`